# Calculating the minimum distance of a linear code

Tags: java, optimization

This is a solution for the problem named [Codes](https://kth.kattis.com/problems/codes) on the *kattis* platform:

> Given a generator matrix of a linear code, calculate the minimum distance of the code.

I'm looking for reviews on optimization and best practices. Code readability should be preserved.

```
public static class LinearCode {
   private int[][] generator;
   private int n;
   private int k;

   public LinearCode(int[][] generator, int n, int k) {
      this.generator = generator;
      this.n = n;
      this.k = k;
   }

   public int getMinimumDistance() {
      int minDistance = n;
      int maxKString = 1 << k;

      // generate all k-strings
      for (int i = 1; i < maxKString; i++) {
          int kstring = i;
          int distance = 0;

          // matrix multiplication
          for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
              int p = 0;
              for (int z = 0; z < k; z++) {
                  int a = generator[j][k-z-1];
                  int b = (kstring >>> z) & 1;
                  p = (p + a * b) & 1;
              }
              // distance as number if 1 bits
              distance += p;
          }

          minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, distance);
      }

      return minDistance;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *performance* of the algorithm can be improved by using a different representation for the generator. Instead of a `n x k` matrix of integers the generator
is stored as a vector of `k` integers representing the columns of the matrix,
using one bit per row.

For example, the matrix

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 1 1
```

would be stored as the vector `{ 0b1001, 0b1010, 0b1100 }`. Binary multiplication of the matrix with a "string"  (i.e. a 0/1 sequence of length `k`) is then simply
done by XOR'ing those columns of the generator matrix for which the 
corresponding bit in the string is set.

For example, the product of the above matrix with `101` would be

```
0b1001 ^ 0b1100 = 0b0101
```

Finally, the hamming distance of this code to the zero code word is the number of 1-bits, in this case `2`.

The main method of your program then becomes (using the code from @janos's review as a starting point):

```
public static int getMinimumDistance(int[][] generator) {
    int n = generator.length;
    int k = generator[0].length;
    int minDistance = n;
    int maxKString = 1 << k;

    // Compute vector of "columns" from the given generator:
    int genColumns[] = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        int column = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            column += generator[j][i] << j;
        }
        genColumns[i] = column;
    }

    // For all input strings:
    for (int kString = 1; kString < maxKString; kString++) {

        // matrix multiplication
        int code = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (((kString >>> i) & 1) != 0) {
                code ^= genColumns[i];
            }
        }

        int distance = Integer.bitCount(code);
        minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, distance);
    }
    return minDistance;
}
```

This works as long as the length of the code word `n` is less than 32.

For a `28 x 7` generator matrix, this method reduces the computation time
from 0.8 ms to 0.08 ms on my computer.

*Update:* Here is the test/timing code. (I simply took the sample matrix from
https://kth.kattis.com/problems/codes, duplicated the rows several times to get 28 rows, then duplicated the last 2 columns to get 7 columns, and finally modified the new
columns slightly to get a non-zero distance for the generator.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int distance = CodeDistance.getMinimumDistance(new int[][]{

        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},

    });
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println(duration/1000000.0 + "ms");

    System.out.println(distance);
}
```

Comment: Nice work! Could you please share the test case?

Comment: @CristianGreco: I have added it to the answer.

Comment: There is a method for the Hamming Distance, [Integer.bitCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount%28int%29)

Comment: @dusky: Oops, yes, thanks! As you can see, Java is not my primary language :) I have updated the code.

Answer (score 11):

The `n` and `k` parameters seem pointless: you can derive them from the dimensions of the received `generator` matrix:

```
int n = generator.length;
int k = generator[0].length;
```

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
> ```

You could replace using for-each, which is just more natural:

```
for (int[] row : generator) {
```

---

I don't really see a reason to store the parameters as fields.
The class doesn't need to hold data.
You need just a *pure function*,
so this can be a `public static` method.

#### Putting it together

Applying the above suggestions (+ a few minor things):

```
public static int getMinimumDistance(int[][] generator) {
    int n = generator.length;
    int k = generator[0].length;
    int minDistance = n;
    int maxKString = 1 << k;

    // generate all k-strings
    for (int i = 1; i < maxKString; i++) {
        int distance = 0;

        // matrix multiplication
        for (int[] row : generator) {
            int p = 0;
            for (int z = 0; z < k; z++) {
                int a = row[k - z - 1];
                int b = (i >>> z) & 1;
                p = (p + a * b) & 1;
            }
            // distance as number if 1 bits
            distance += p;
        }

        minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, distance);
    }

    return minDistance;
}
```

#### Unit testing

I recommend adding unit tests to verify your solution, for example:

```
@Test
public void testSampleExercise1() {
    assertEquals(3, LinearCode.getMinimumDistance(new int[][]{
            {1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1},
            {0, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 0, 1},
    }));
}

@Test
public void testSampleExercise2() {
    assertEquals(0, LinearCode.getMinimumDistance(new int[][]{
            {1, 1},
            {0, 0},
            {1, 1},
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, your changes look reasonable. However, there is no bug actually: the first line of input in the example `3 2` are the `n k` parameters.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I overlooked that. Updated my answer.